# Getting Camera Permission Takes Up To 10 Seconds

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, avfoundation, uialertview

I need to check for camera permissions.

If the permission fails I show an alert. However this takes up 10 seconds to show up (not good!).

Can you think of why its taking so long to get the permissions? I even tried forcing the call on the main thread.

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool)
    {
        checkCameraPermissions()
        if(_viewInitialized == false)
        {
            //_view.initView()
            _viewInitialized = true
            _distanceBetweenTopAndMiddleBar = Int(_middleBar.frame.origin.y) - Int(_topBar.frame.origin.y) - Int(_topBar.frame.height)
        }
    }

    func checkCameraPermissions()
    {
        var status:AVAuthorizationStatus = AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatusForMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
        if(status == AVAuthorizationStatus.Authorized)
        {
            return
        }else
        {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())
            {
                AVCaptureDevice.requestAccessForMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
                {
                    allowed in
                    if(allowed == true)
                    {
                        return
                    }else
                    {
                        var alert:UIAlertView = UIAlertView(title: "Permission", message: "Ok", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
                        alert.show()
                        alert.tag = 1
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried without the dispatch?

Comment: Yup still no show, at least til 10 seconds

Comment: Also, curious, it doesnt ask me for permission, it goes straight to denied. Should I get a dialoge coming up asking me for access to the camera when I requestAccessForMediaType?

Comment: Did you include the `NSCameraUsageDescription` key in your `info.plist`?